# jQuery .val() not returning what is expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement the following code snippet into my project: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmf6t/. But I am running into a bit of difficulty; I have wrapped the JavaScript in the `jQuery(document).ready()` callback function, and checking it in the Chrome debugger shows that the script is running. However, when I get to the `if( jQuery(this).val() == "-1" )` (as my `<select>` value has `-1` as its value), the debugger reports that the elements `value` property is `"-1"`, but the statement within the `if` is never evaluated. Instead the `else` property is evaluated.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I cannot seem to isolate the issue to provide a minimal working example; my jQuery is as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {    
    jQuery('#test').change( function() {
        if( jQuery(this).val() == "-1" )
        {
            jQuery(this).addClass( "empty-combo" );
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery(this).removeClass( "empty-combo" );
        }
    });

    jQuery('#test').change();
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xtxtfmth/ Wrap your code in [document-ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler

Comment: try to show us  `console.log( jQuery(this).val() );`

Comment: @Legendary It simply returns `null` which is in contrast to what the Chrome inspect element scope variables claims `value` of the element is?

Comment: yes, so u can change condition to if( jQuery(this).val() == null )  @Shaktal

Comment: @Shaktal you welcome, dont forget to approve ans for improving SO )

Comment: your code works, check the console here : http://jsfiddle.net/txLdc284/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your condition to:

```
if( jQuery(this).val() == null )
```

It worked.